# Android- Sharing local storage on multiple WebViews/Windows

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, local-storage

I'm developping a mobile application, which should connect to a web server. The application is written with jQM and simply imported in an android web view. I tried to solve this problem using the jStorage plugin, but it seems that it's impossible to share the local storage between the different pages. So I tried to implement [this](https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage), but it does not work and continues sending `null`.

Here are my code samples: 
Javascript:

```
function getToken(authCode) {
    var jsonUrl = mainUrl + "/auth/authorizeToken?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=bc89fb879a64eb8e422b94d5c39&client_secret=b5c2974b78f7f3f7aee2bed182&redirect_uri=redirection&code="+authCode;
    $.ajax({
        url: jsonUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem( "access_token", data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem( "refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
            localStorage.setItem( "logged", "true");
        }
    });
}

function valTokens() {
    access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
}
```

After that the values are set to null. The .java files are the same as in the sample from the link given.